# Is there a shortcut to expand lines in IDEA and VIM

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, shortcut

I already know Join Lines shortcut in VIM(Shift + J) and IDEA(Alt + Shift + J)

```
{
   var a = 1;
}
```

to

```
{var a=1;}
```

Is there a shortcut to revert?
I want to easily expand code like this in HTML.

```
<div>hello</div>
```

to

```
<div>
    hello
<div>
```

Comment: Configure your HTML/XML code style settings to have the blank line and reformat the code.

Comment: There is a plugin for vim https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim

Comment: "Shift + J" is "J".

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
<div>something else</div>
```

You could try this

```
:%s/>\zs[^<]*\ze<\//\r\t&\r

> ................... end of <div>
\zs ................. start of the match
[^<]* ............... anything but <
\ze ................. end of the match
< ................... start of <div>
\/ .................. protected slash "/"
\r .................. carriage return (Enter)
\t .................. tab
& ................... matched pattern in the search portion
```